# Hadoop/cygwin failure in bin/hadoop tasktracker command

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

i am following http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html

Start the namenode in the first window by executing
cd hadoop-0.19.1
bin/hadoop namenode
Start the secondary namenode in the second window by executing
cd hadoop-0.19.1
bin/hadoop secondarynamenode
Start the job tracker the third window by executing
cd hadoop-0.19.1
bin/hadoop jobtracker
Start the data node the fourth window by executing
cd hadoop-0.19.1
bin/hadoop datanode
Start the task tracker the fifth window by executing
cd hadoop-0.19.1
bin/hadoop tasktracker

till "bin/hadoop datanode" is working fine the last one for "bin/hadoop tasktracker"

this is what i gets

```
`$ bin/hadoop tasktracker
bin/hadoop: line 350: C:\Program: command not found
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = xxxx/10.10.200.94
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1479473; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Mon May  6 06:59:37 UTC 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_21
************************************************************/
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
13/05/22 09:42:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Instantiating workaround file system
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as xxxx
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /tmp/hadoop-xxxx/mapred/local
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Ignoring IOException setting persmission for path "/tmp/hadoop-xxx/mapred/local/taskTracker": Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-xxxx\mapred\local\taskTracker to 0755
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Ignoring IOException setting persmission for path "/tmp/hadoop-xxxx/mapred/local/ttprivate": Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-xxxx\mapred\local\ttprivate to 0700
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Ignoring IOException setting persmission for path "/tmp/hadoop-xxx/mapred/local/tt_log_tmp": Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-xxxx\mapred\local\tt_log_tmp to 0755
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source TaskTrackerMetrics registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort53336 registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort53336 registered.
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 53336: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 53336: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 53336: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 53336: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 53336: starting
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker up at: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:53336
13/05/22 09:42:15 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tracker tracker_xxxx.local:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:53336
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Starting thread: Map-events fetcher for all reduce tasks on tracker_xxx.local:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:53336
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.TaskTracker:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
13/05/22 09:42:16 WARN util.ProcessTree: setsid is not available on this machine. So not using it.
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: ProcessTree implementation is missing on this system. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.IndexCache: IndexCache created with max memory = 10485760
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ShuffleServerMetrics registered.
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50060
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50060 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50060
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50060
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50060
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: FILE_CACHE_SIZE for mapOutputServlet set to : 2000
13/05/22 09:42:16 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:21 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:24 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:26 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:30 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:32 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:33 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:35 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:36 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
13/05/22 09:42:40 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
```

`

could someone please help......

Comment: Having gone through the hell of trying to get it all to work myself, I'd strongly advise against trying to use Hadoop with Cygwin. A virtual machine is probably your best bet if you are confined to a Windows environment.

Comment: ofcourse im trying with both vm player and local system too. its kind of hard time going through. i could find only few tutorials all does differently. im new to it.

Comment: i was able to do till last step of the tutorial, and i used hadoop-0.19.1 version what said in the tutorial. this time i got issue in java. exception thrown, some java library class version compatibility issue while try to run the java code. : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of space within the Java JDK's file path "Program Files". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378199/hadoop-configuration-on-windows-through-cygwin) is a work around to fix the problem