# Cannot link Java with Hadoop installed using Cygwin

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run hadoop using cygwin in Windows 7 machine but I am encountering an error while trying to start hadoop.

> $ bin/hadoop namenode -format
>
> : No such file or directoryrive/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java
>
> : No such file or directoryrive/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java
>
> : cannot execute: No such file or directorygram
>   Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java

I have made the following changes.

In `C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop-0.20.2\conf\hadoop-env.sh`,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/ and in C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop-0.20.2\bin\hadoop

JAVA_PLATFORM=CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}" "${JAVA}" -Xmx32m ${HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS} org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName | sed -e "s/ /_/g"
```

as mentioned in [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378199/hadoop-configuration-on-windows-through-cygwin/18287523#18287523).

but still I am getting the same error.
Please help!!!

Comment: Those changes that you made "export JAVA_HOME" etc - were you following their guide (in which case they might be different for you), or are those your actual locations?

Comment: Is it  `directoryrive/c` or directory `directory cygdrive/c`?

Comment: Try this instead in the hadoop-env.sh: `export JAVA_HOME=c:\\Program\ Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17`
 - And, do don't have to modify anything in `JAVA_PLATFORM`